# Meter varias variables en cadena de texto

Tags: php, string, http-get

Muy buenas, tengo una  variable llamada origen, donde quiero guardar una cadena de texto con dos variables. Esa variable la paso por get a una pagina (2) usando la funcion load.

El problema es que cuando hago un alert de origen  desde la pagina (2), me muestra solo la primera variable pero no la segunda.

Así capturo el valor de origen desde pagina (2).

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['origen'])){  ?>
        origen=<?php echo "'".$_GET['origen']."'";}?>;
```

Variable origen

```
  origen='php/formTarea.php?idMisTareas='+idTarea+'&idHis='+historia;
```

Aqui voy a pagina (2) pasando origen por get

```
 load('php/formHistoria.php?idHis='+historia+'&idTarea='+idTarea+'&origen='+origen);
```

Comment: Lo que hace GET es crear un array usando cada `&` de la URL como separador. En dicho array la clave es lo que hay antes del signo `=` y el valor es lo que hay después de ese signo. Para acceder a esos valores tendrías que usar `$_GET["clave"]`. O sea: `$_GET["idHis"]`, `$_GET["idTarea"]` ... etc.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta Pablo, el caso es que yo origen no lo quiero desglosar en sus variables, lo quiero usar para hacer un load con su ruta, mi intención es en el botón de "Anterior"  que me cargue la dirección que le paso con la variable load. El problema es que me corta en la variable MisTareas=...  Así, desde la pagina A abro la pagina B mandandole la ruta  de la pagina A para poder ponerla en el boton de anterior. Esa es mi idea. Esto lo tengo que hacer así por que las paginas las cargo en el mismo div.

Comment: No entiendo del todo el planteamiento del problema en la pregunta. Tu último comentario no obstante me hace pensar que lo ideal sería traer lo que necesites del servidor mediante una petición Ajax, que actuaría en background, de forma totalmente transparente, y te permitirá actualizar tu div sin tener que refrescar la página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pasar variables por js

```
url:   'index.php?accion=modificar&idRepresentante='+idRepresentante+'&cp='+cp,
```

pasar variables por php

```
<form id="formEditar" method="POST" role="form" action="index.php?accion=actualizar&idRepresentante=<?php echo $_GET['idRepresentante'];?>">
```

recibir en variables por GET

```
$recibir = $_GET["idRepresentante"];
```

recibir variables por POST

```
$recibir = $_POST["idRepresentante"];

$origen .= $_GET["idRepresentante"];
```

valida en el network que estas enviado bien las varibles y que esten llegando al destino.

saludos